# Numpy only computation of mathematical expression involving a nested sum of functions over the same array

Tags: python, numpy

I need help to compute a mathematical expression using only numpy operations. The expression I want to compute is the following :

[image]

Where : x is an (N, S) array and f is a numpy function (that can work with broadcastable arrays e.g np.maximum, np.sum, np.prod, ...). If that is of importance, in my case f is a symetric function.

So far my code looks like this:

```py
s = 0
for xp in x: # Loop over N...
    s += np.sum(np.prod(f(xp, x), axis=1))
```

And still has loop that I'd like to get rid of.

Typically N is "large" (around 30k) but S is small (less than 20) so if anyone can find a trick to only loop over S this would still be a major improvement.

I belive the problem is easy by N-plicating the array but one of size (32768, 32768, 20) requires 150Go of RAM that I don't have. However, (32768, 32768) fits in memory though I would appreciate a solution that does not allocate such array.

Maybe a use of np.einsum with well-chosen arrays is possible?

Thanks for your replies. If any information is missing let me know!

Have a nice day !

**Edit 1** :

Form of f I'm interested in includes (for now) : f(x, y) = |x - y|, f(x, y) = |x - y|^2, f(x, y) = 2 - max(x, y).

Comment: We can't help with a generic `f`.  First can if wrk with small space `np.sum(np.prod(f(...), axis=2), axis=(0,1))`?  If the only problem is with large arrays, you may well have to work some skrt batches.  Trading off memory use against batched iteration is well known issue.

Comment: I'm interested in multiple expression for f and the list can and will be extanded in the future. But I can provide some of them that may open new leads. f(x, y) = |x - y|,  f(x, y) = |x - y|^2, f(x, y) = 2 - max(x, y). The real problem with large array are the loop over them, not the fact that they are large in itself.

Comment: Work with your data in batches.

Comment: OK, so you aren't worried so much about memory as about speed, trying to reduce the problem space first by doing the `N` sums, and then doing the `S` prod.  That sounds more like an algebra problem, changing `a*b+c*d` to some sort of (a+c)*(b+c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is very efficient. Some possible ways are

**Method-1 (looping over S)**

```
import numpy as np
def f(x,y):
    return np.abs(x-y)
N = 200
S = 20
x_data = random.rand(N,S) #(i,s)
y_data = random.rand(N,S) #(i',s)
product = f(broadcast_to(x_data[:,0][...,None],(N,N)) ,broadcast_to(y_data[:,0][...,None],(N,N)).T)
for i in range(1,S):
    product *= f(broadcast_to(x_data[:,i][...,None],(N,N)) ,broadcast_to(y_data[:,i][...,None],(N,N)).T)

sum = np.sum(product)
```

**Method-2 (dispatching S number of blocks)**

```
import numpy as np
def f(x,y):
    x1 = np.broadcast_to(x[:,None,...],(x.shape[0],y.shape[0],x.shape[1]))
    y1 = np.broadcast_to(y[None,...],(x.shape[0],y.shape[0],x.shape[1]))
    return np.abs(x1-y1)
def f1(x1,y1):
    return np.abs(x1-y1)
N = 5000
S = 20
x_data = np.random.rand(N,S) #(i,s)
y_data = np.random.rand(N,S) #(i',s)
def fun_new(x_data1,y_data1):
    s = 0
    pp =np.split(x_data1,S,axis=0)
    for xp in pp:
        s += np.sum(np.prod(f(xp, y_data1), axis=2))
    return s
def fun_op(x_data1,y_data1):
    s = 0
    for xp in x_data1: # Loop over N...
        s += np.sum(np.prod(f1(xp, y_data1), axis=1))
    return s

fun_new(x_data,y_data)
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm! If anyone interested : In my case the first solution leads to a speedup of 3 (but the code is part of a larger function with other numpy computation). The second solution appears to be slower while consuming the same amount of memory so I would not recommand it, but that's works too.